# Rails Syntax error in if Statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, web, model-view-controller

Hello i think i'm blind and i don't find the bug in the syntax

```
def update
  @list = List.find_by(key: params[:id])
  if (check_email_link(params[:expdate] && @list.update(wishlist_params))
    flash[:notice] = t("update")
    redirect_to (admin_list_url)
  else
    flash[:error] = t("not_active")
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

The expdate contains a datetimestamp and the check_email_link is a method that checks the date and time of a link in the mail

There are three syntax errors

```
app/controllers/admin/lists_controller.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting ')'
app/controllers/admin/lists_controller.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
app/controllers/admin/lists_controller.rb:86: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

I'm an idiot or i'm blind. Can someone help an explain me the error? Thanks

Comment: You're missing the closing parentheses for `check_email_link` on the third line.

Comment: In your check_email_link call, the params[:expdate] misses the closing `)`.

Comment: in ruby you don't typically surround the clause in an `if` statement with parens, so you could actually leave them out

Comment: Further to Mario's comment, I believe the convention is to put parentheses around an `if` condition if and only if it is also an assignment.

Comment: @amarradi - if you "accept" an answer - you can then tell that the question has been "solved"... Remember that it's always ok to answer a question yourself if you have a solution different to the ones given :)

Comment: Please do not add "solved" in a title. Instead, mark an answer as "accepted" using the green checkmark next to the answer of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

`(check_email_link(params[:expdate] && @list.update(wishlist_params))` has three `(`s and two `)`s. You need either another `)` or one less `(`. I can't be sure where, as I don't know your code.

While we're on it, the `if` line shouldn't be indented the extra level, as it kinda makes it look like the line *above* starts a block.

Comment: Yes, thats interessting. maybe someone is jealous because you were faster

Comment: You probably got a downvote because this was covered by two comments (which were noted as the answer) before you answered and because most people know that this will get closed as a "just a typo" question.

Comment: 1, surely comments shouldn't be used for answers, since answers exist. 2, those comments hadn't shown up on my screen before I submitted the answer.